# Fixed header with min-width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fixed header on a page, using `position: fixed;`.

The idea is that I want to add to that header a min-width, so that on a window smaller than 800px, the entire content (along with the header) would be scrollable.

From my research, I found out that there isn't any CSS solution. But what would be the JS-one?

[JSFiddle example](http://bit.ly/1E53iJh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply following css:

```
@media all and (max-width:400px){
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top {
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

This will give your desirable output. When your window width go below `400px;` then your header will be scrollable. You can change it with `800px;` or whichever your need.

Check Your updated [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6707/)

**Edit:**

You have to learn [media query](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) for that. In your code `navbar` have position fixed. Here we apply media query like: `@media all and (max-width:400px)`. It means if window width lessthan  `400px` then it's position we set `relative`. like: `position: relative;`.

This media query css apply upto **max-width** of `400px;` you can change it as per your requirement. You can learn more from [Here.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Can you briefly explain WHY is this working?

Comment: Yes, but the header is not going to be fixed anymore. Is there a way to make the header fixed and scrollable, at the same time? 
@ketan

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS media queries to style things differently based on the window width. In the below example, the header will be fixed only if the window width is 800 pixels or more.

**EXAMPLE**

```
@media all and (min-width:800px){
    header{
      position:fixed;
    }
}
```

[More informartion on media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: max-width:800px -> since the window should be SMALLER than 800px :D

Comment: From the original question: "on a window smaller than 800px, the entire content (along with the header) would be scrollable." Therefore >=800px, it should be fixed - `min-width` is correct here.

Comment: yea but smaller than 800px doesnt support anything thats lower than 800, so if you scale it down to 799 then your media query wont worky any more.

But thats an unnecessary discussion haha
you helped him :)

Comment: @noa-dev: "so if you scale it down to 799 then your media query wont worky any more."That's exactly what CrazyDog is looking for; `fixed` if window width is 800px or more, normal if window width is less than 800px.